# Run separate process from .net core program in docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

I have a .net core program that will run from docker.
This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
COPY / App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ParentConsole.dll"]
```

This program will run a separate program as a process. Example:

```
Process.Start("childconsole.exe","")
```

However, that process always throw error with exit code:
-1073741515

The same program (ParentConsole) can run fine as a normal windows app.
Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Obvious question: did you copy `childconsole.exe` into the container? Another question: how do you expect to run windows executables in a (presumably) linux container?

Comment: it is a windows container. yes, the file is there. it is confirmed by File.Exists(childconsole.exe)

Comment: Can you run the childconsole by itself? Outside of your app? Maybe it container doesn't have a dll file / system component it needs?

Comment: yes, the childconsole can run fine by itself. the error message / error code looks different when the dll cannot be found.

Comment: the childconsole is working if I use Process.Start("dotnet","childconsole.dll"). however, I am looking to call the .exe file directly.

Comment: Is childconsole.exe a .NET Core application?  What version of .NET Core is it based on?  Hopefully it's .NET Core 3.1.  Otherwise, it would need to have been published as a self-contained app.